# MYSQL - How to update a table from a sub query with 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MYSQL and i have a query with multiple joins in it but the end result is that query produces 2 columns.  I wish to update a column in a table based on those 2 columns.

Example, my query with the all the joins produces the below results with the following 2 columns.

```
column1:    column2:  
john          23        
Lisa          45        
Tim           56        
etc.......
```

The total rows returned is about 100.  The table i'm trying to update has 3 columns in it. I want to update column 3 based only on the combination of the 2 rows that my query produces. I know the below doesn't work but just using it to illustrate what i'm trying to do.

```
update table1
set column3 = valuex
where column1 and column2
in
(this is my query with the joins that produces the 2 columns referenced above)
```

This is where i want to say 'apply this update only based on the rows with the combination of the 2 columns of my original query'

Hope i worded my question clearly enough:) Thanks !!

Comment: You should at least also include what the output table looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you merely got the syntax for the `IN` clause wrong:

```
update table1
set column3 = @valuex
where (column1, column2) in ( <your query here> );
```

Comment: That was exactly it !! It was driving me flat out CRAZY : ) This was just what i needed.  Thanks a lot Thorsten !! 

Side note, when I updated the statement and ran it, i got a '#1093 - You can't specify target table 'xxx' for update in FROM clause' error message.   The trick to that was to  use a subquery.  Like this: 

update table1
set column3 = @valuex
where (column1, column2) in 
 
(select column1, column2 from
( <my query here> )T);

That worked perfectly.  Thanks again sir !!!

Answer (score 0):

update table1 set column3 = @valuex where (column1, column2) in (select column1, column2 from (  )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the multi-table syntax:

```
UPDATE table1
    JOIN t2  ON ...
    JOIN t3  ON ...
    SET  table1.col3 = valx;
```

Comment: Appreciate your response Rick James : )